# (MediaWiki) Table inside a Table, but containing styles?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to add such a Table:

```
{|
|+ style="border:solid 1px grey; margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;"|'''Header of Image'''
! style="border:solid 2px grey;"|[[Datei:Image.png|link=LinkToGo]]
|}
```

Inside another table, to create a grid of Header+Image combos, the viewer can navigate with.

Problem now:
If I do it that way (with a Table of 2 columns and 1 row):

```
{|
|+
|-
| {|
|+ style="border:solid 1px grey; margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;"|'''Die Welt'''
! style="border:solid 2px grey;"|[[Datei:NoImage_192.png|link=Main Page]]
|}|| {|
|+ style="border:solid 1px grey; margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;"|'''Die Welt'''
! style="border:solid 2px grey;"|[[Datei:NoImage_192.png|link=Main Page]]
|}
|}
```

I'm ending up with this mess:

[image]

So… how would one do that stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table start/end tags are all on standalone lines.

Also, while the style parameters weren't related to your specific issue, you are probably better off using CSS and the TemplateStyles extension.